# Communication Between Steps having huge amount of data (List<Id> 21000 qty)

Tags: spring-batch

I have following scenario , But could not figure it out how to implement.

1. populate the list from select id from table.
2. I have currently having job with step1 chunk orientated step
   In ItemWriter I have to remove element if present in the list above example list.remove(id)
3. If list is not empty then i have to perform Update operation on the table based on IDs present in the list

Step 2 :chunk oriented step is working fine , i have to integrate the 1 and 3rd
Shall I use Step1 tasklet where as follows:

public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
// Fetch data from the database and create the list of Acct
List acct = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT id FROM Account",
new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Acct.class));

```
    // Store the list in StepExecutionContext to pass it to Step 2
    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().put("acct", acct);

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

How do i retrieve the list in chunk oriented step ?? Please help here

I need help communication between steps

Answer (score 0):

> // Store the list in StepExecutionContext to pass it to Step 2
> chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().put("acct", acct);

You need to promote this key to the job execution context in order to get access to it in subsequent steps. Currently you are putting the key in the step execution context, which is not visible to the next step.